# Pattern Lab: changing the title

Tags: html, title, mustache, head, patternlab.io

The title is currently 'Pattern Lab' and I can't seem to change it. I've tried changing it in '_00-head.mustache' and also in '_data.json' but neither works.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title in this file:
./core/templates/index.mustache

You will need to generate the ./public after using the PHP cmd: 
php core/builder.php